# Java: how to convert a List<?> to a Map<String,?>

Tags: java, generics, list, dictionary

I would like to find a way to take the object specific routine below and abstract it into a method that you can pass a class, list, and fieldname to get back a Map.
If I could get a general pointer on the pattern used  or , etc that could get me started in the right direction.

```
  Map<String,Role> mapped_roles = new HashMap<String,Role>();
    List<Role> p_roles = (List<Role>) c.list();
    for (Role el :  p_roles) {
        mapped_roles.put(el.getName(), el);
    }
```

to this? (Pseudo code)

```
  Map<String,?> MapMe(Class clz, Collection list, String methodName)
  Map<String,?> map = new HashMap<String,?>();
    for (clz el :  list) {
        map.put(el.methodName(), el);
    }
```

is it possible?

Comment: @Aircule: One could use the old functor hack just fine here.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to have a list of `x`  thing and convert it to a map where the key is the thing name and the value is the thing?

Comment: right, the key is a string value returned from the method passed (object Person has method name(), persons name becomes the key), the value is the object itself. Its much easier to compare strings than having to have an object on hand for comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I would do. I am not entirely sure if I am handling generics right, but oh well:

```
public <T> Map<String, T> mapMe(Collection<T> list) {
   Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<String, T>();
   for (T el : list) {
       map.put(el.toString(), el);
   }   
   return map;
}
```

Just pass a Collection to it, and have your classes implement toString() to return the name. Polymorphism will take care of it.

Comment: I like the idea of using this vs reflection, Ill have to implement both methods. Thanks

Comment: Since this only works with `toString()` as the function for getting the index key, it's not a very good general solution and obviously doesn't work for any arbitrary property of an object. The reflection solution is even worse and breaks without compiler errors on refactoring.

Comment: Well in that case you can use
public static <T extends BaseModel> Map<String, T>. with BaseModel containing for example the field id and getId() ... Obviously this will only works if the Set of object you are trying to convert into map is of type BaseModel

Answer (score 33):

Using [Guava (formerly Google Collections)](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex(java.lang.Iterable,com.google.common.base.Function)):

```
Map<String,Role> mappedRoles = Maps.uniqueIndex(yourList, Functions.toStringFunction());
```

Or, if you want to supply your own method that makes a `String` out of the object:

```
Map<String,Role> mappedRoles = Maps.uniqueIndex(yourList, new Function<Role,String>() {
  public String apply(Role from) {
    return from.getName(); // or something else
  }});
```

Comment: I'd recommend linking to Guava rather than Google Collections, as Guava has officially superseded it.

Comment: I don't *think* the questioner wants `Object.toString`. Or at least the question seems to imply not wanting it.

Comment: @Tom Then he only has to supply his own function instead of the prefab toString one

Comment: @Jorn Nice to see you've added a solution to your answer that answers the question! With a big dependency.

Comment: @Tom What dependency do you mean?

Comment: @Jorn Dependency on Google Collections.

Comment: @Tom I feel like Google Collections/Guava is a library that most Java projects could benefit from. Especially if the alternative is reimplementing its functionality from scratch and in a more limiting fashion (like your answer) or doing something... unsafe... like the reflection answer.

Comment: @Tom That dependency was already there in the first part of the answer. And Colin explains perfectly why it's an asset to have the dependency instead of a cost like you're implying

Comment: Google Guava project is moved [GitHub](https://github.com/google/guava).

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 streams and method references make this so easy you don't need a helper method for it.

```
Map<String, Foo> map = listOfFoos.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getName, Function.identity()));
```

If there may be duplicate keys, you can aggregate the values with the [toMap overload that takes a value merge function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), or you can use [groupingBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) to collect into a list:

```
//taken right from the Collectors javadoc
Map<Department, List<Employee>> byDept = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment));
```

As shown above, none of this is specific to String -- you can create an index on any type.

If you have a lot of objects to process and/or your indexing function is expensive, you can go parallel by using `Collection.parallelStream()` or `stream().parallel()` ([they do the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603186/why-does-collection-parallelstream-exist-when-stream-parallel-does-the-sa)).  In that case you might use [toConcurrentMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) or [groupingByConcurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingByConcurrent-java.util.function.Function-), as they allow the stream implementation to just blast elements into a ConcurrentMap instead of making separate maps for each thread and then merging them.

If you don't want to commit to `Foo::getName` (or any specific method) at the call site, you can use a Function passed in by a caller, stored in a field, etc..  Whoever actually creates the Function can still take advantage of method reference or lambda syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid reflection like the plague.

Unfortunately, Java's syntax for this is verbose. (A recent JDK7 proposal would make it much more consise.)

```
interface ToString<T> {
    String toString(T obj);
}

public static <T> Map<String,T> stringIndexOf(
    Iterable<T> things,
    ToString<T> toString
) {
    Map<String,T> map = new HashMap<String,T>();
    for (T thing : things) {
        map.put(toString.toString(thing), thing);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Currently call as:

```
Map<String,Thing> map = stringIndexOf(
    things,
    new ToString<Thing>() { public String toString(Thing thing) {
        return thing.getSomething();
    }
);
```

In JDK7, it may be something like:

```
Map<String,Thing> map = stringIndexOf(
    things,
    { thing -> thing.getSomething(); }
);
```

(Might need a `yield` in there.)

Comment: verbose and about as clear as mud :), would requiring a toString method be more pragmatic?

Comment: @ebt I don't think there's anything wrong with the clarity. Well names could be better chosen. / I don't understand your comment about a `toString` method. Do you mean `Object.toString` on `T` - that wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: ok, took me several iterations to piece it together. Implementing toString requires that your input objects implement toString instead of assuming that the toString method exists and throws an error at runtime (although you could add throws on the method right?)

Comment: never mind, idiotic question. toString is inherited from Object... palm -> face.

Comment: +1 for avoid reflection

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection and generics:

```
public static <T> Map<String, T> MapMe(Class<T> clz, Collection<T> list, String methodName)
throws Exception{
  Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<String, T>();
  Method method = clz.getMethod(methodName);
  for (T el : list){
    map.put((String)method.invoke(el), el);
  }
  return map;
}
```

In your documentation, make sure you mention that the return type of the method must be a String. Otherwise, it will throw a ClassCastException when it tries to cast the return value.

Comment: +1 At times like these I wish there was a "favorite answer" option.

Comment: -1 - this might work on a good day, but it is fragile ... and probably a lot more expensive than the original code.

Comment: There's no sane reason to do it this way, just use a Function instead of reflection

Comment: @Stephen C: What do you mean it's "fragile"?  It works perfectly, as long as the programmer passes in the right method name.

Comment: @mangst - it breaks (with no compilation errors) if the programmer passes the wrong name or the method's signature changes, or the list signature changes ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that each object in the `List` will have a unique index, use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) with Jorn's suggestion of `Maps.uniqueIndex`.

If, on the other hand, more than one object may have the same value for the index field (which, while not true for your specific example perhaps, is true in many use cases for this sort of thing), the more general way do this indexing is to use [Multimaps.index(Iterable<V> values, Function<? super V,K> keyFunction)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) to create an `ImmutableListMultimap<K,V>` that maps each key to one or more matching values.

Here's an example that uses a custom `Function` that creates an index on a specific property of an object:

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
ImmutableListMultimap<String, Foo> index = Multimaps.index(foos,
    new Function<Foo, String>() {
      public String apply(Foo input) {
        return input.getBar();
      }
    });

// iterate over all Foos that have "baz" as their Bar property
for (Foo foo : index.get("baz")) { ... }
```