# How to convert List to Map?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, hashmap, java-stream

Recently I have conversation with a colleague about what would be the optimal way to convert `List` to `Map` in Java and if there any specific benefits of doing so.

I want to know optimal conversion approach and would really appreciate if any one can guide me.

Is this good approach:

```
List<Object[]> results;
Map<Integer, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (Object[] o : results) {
    resultsMap.put((Integer) o[0], (String) o[1]);
}
```

Comment: What's the best optimal way? Optimization is done with certain parameter (speed/memory) in mind.

Comment: List differs from Map in the conceptual way -- Map have notion of 'key, value' pair, whereas List doesn't. Given this it's unclear how exactly you going to convert from List to Map and back.

Comment: @Daniel: By Optimal, I meant what is the best way of doing so among all different ways between am not sure of all the ways and so it would be good to see some different ways of converting list to map.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: how to convert a List<?> to a Map<String,?>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199657/java-how-to-convert-a-list-to-a-mapstring)

Comment: Read this article: [How to Convert List to Map in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-to-map)

Comment: Java 8 HashMap and not any map implementation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47736750/1216775

Answer (score 220, accepted):

```
List<Item> list;
Map<Key,Item> map = new HashMap<Key,Item>(list.size());
for (Item i : list) map.put(i.getKey(),i);
```

Assuming of course that each Item has a `getKey()` method that returns a key of the proper type.

Comment: You could also key on the position in the list.

Comment: @Jim: Do i need to set the `getKey()` to any specific parameter ?

Comment: Also what would be the value in the Map, can you elaborate with an example ?

Comment: @Rachel -- The value is the item in the list, and the key is something  that makes the item unique, which is determined by you. Jim's use of `getKey()` was arbitrary.

Comment: @Jeremy: Ok. So basically I have element position in the list as the key and its value as value to populate the map, right ?

Comment: What could be other ways of doing so ?

Comment: Also, I have updated question with one approach that I have used, is this correct way of doing so ?

Comment: @Rachel No, you are using the same element as the key and value for ALL the objects.  This will result in only one element being added to the list. If the list contains n elements, you will be adding the same duplicate map entry n times.

Comment: You know the size beforehand so you can do

Map<Key,Item> map = new HashMap<Key,Item>(list.size());

Comment: Clean and adequate, and does not require a callback function for every item you process. By far the best response no matter what fancy stream or utility function is available.

Answer (score 461):

With [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you'll be able to do this in one line using [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), and the [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class.

```
Map<String, Item> map = 
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getKey, item -> item));
```

Short demo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        List<Item> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4)
                                   .mapToObj(Item::new)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()); //[Item [i=1], Item [i=2], Item [i=3], Item [i=4]]

        Map<String, Item> map = 
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getKey, item -> item));

        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " => " + v));
    }
}
class Item {

    private final int i;

    public Item(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    public String getKey(){
        return "Key-"+i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [i=" + i + "]";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Key-1 => Item [i=1]
Key-2 => Item [i=2]
Key-3 => Item [i=3]
Key-4 => Item [i=4]
```

As noted in comments, you can use `Function.identity()` instead of `item -> item`, although I find `i -> i` rather explicit.

And to be complete note that you can use a binary operator if your function is not bijective. For example let's consider this `List` and the mapping function that for an int value, compute the result of it modulo 3:

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
Map<String, Integer> map = 
    intList.stream().collect(toMap(i -> String.valueOf(i % 3), i -> i));
```

When running this code, you'll get an error saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 1`. This is because 1 % 3 is the same as 4 % 3 and hence have the same key value given the key mapping function. In this case you can provide a merge operator.

Here's one that sum the values; `(i1, i2) -> i1 + i2;` that can be replaced with the method reference `Integer::sum`.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = 
    intList.stream().collect(toMap(i -> String.valueOf(i % 3), 
                                   i -> i, 
                                   Integer::sum));
```

which now outputs:

```
0 => 9 (i.e 3 + 6)
1 => 5 (i.e 1 + 4)
2 => 7 (i.e 2 + 5)
```

Comment: better use `Function.identity()` instead of `item -> item`

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery Well, `Function.identity()` returns `t -> t;`.

Comment: Sure, both work. I guess it's a matter of taste. I find Function.identity() more immediately recognizable.

Comment: OP doesnt handle any pojos, just strings and integer on whom you cannot cal `::getKey`.

Comment: @Blauhirn I know, my example is based on the custom class just below. You are free to use whatever function to generate your keys from the values .

Comment: Using streams you will loose on performance, unless you are processing really big datasets - read comments here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658322/java-8-performance-of-streams-vs-collections 

And here you can find more general an article on this:

https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html

Comment: FYI, [stream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/stream/package-summary) API was added in API Level 24 in Android

Comment: Nice one @AlexisC. this was very helpful to me :)

Answer (score 113):

Just in case this question isn't closed as a duplicate, [the right answer is to use Google Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3199899/11236):

```
Map<String,Role> mappedRoles = Maps.uniqueIndex(yourList, new Function<Role,String>() {
  public String apply(Role from) {
    return from.getName(); // or something else
  }});
```

Comment: "*[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/#Important_Warnings) contains a strictly compatible superset of **the old, deprecated Google Collections Library**. You should not use that library anymore.*" An update might be needed.

Comment: Use of an external library for such a simple operation is overkill. That or a sign of a very weak standard library.  In this case @jim-garrison's answer is perfectly reasonable. It's sad that java doesn't have helpful methods like "map" and "reduce" but not entirely necessary.

Comment: This uses Guava.  Unfortunately Guava is super slow on Android, so this solution shouldn't be used in an Android project.

Comment: if the item in the list has duplicated roleNames, the above code will throws exception,

Comment: This returns a ImmutableMap. Is there an alternative to this which returns a normal Mutable Map?

Answer (score 47):

Short and sweet.

Using Java 8 you can do following :

```
Map<Key, Value> result= results
                       .stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Value::getName,Function.identity()));
```

`Value` can be any object you use.

Answer (score 21):

Alexis has already posted an answer in **Java 8** using method `toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper)`. As per [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) for this method implementation:

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or
>   thread-safety of the Map returned.

So in case we are interested in a specific implementation of `Map` interface e.g. `HashMap` then we can use the overloaded form as:

```
Map<String, Item> map2 =
                itemList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getKey, //key for map
                        Function.identity(),    // value for map
                        (o,n) -> o,             // merge function in case of conflict with keys
                        HashMap::new));         // map factory - we want HashMap and not any Map implementation
```

Though using either `Function.identity()` or `i->i` is fine but it seems `Function.identity()` instead of `i -> i` might save some memory as per this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041480/1216775).

Comment: The funny fact that in 2019 huge amount of people still not realize that they are not know real Map implementation they get with lambda! Actually this is just one answer I found with Java 8 lambdas I would use on production.

Comment: Is there a way to collect by specifying a Map type but without using a merge function?

Answer (score 18):

Since Java 8, the [answer by @ZouZou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887747) using the `Collectors.toMap` collector is certainly the idiomatic way to solve this problem.

And as this is such a common task, we can make it into a static utility.

That way the solution truly becomes a one-liner.

```
/**
 * Returns a map where each entry is an item of {@code list} mapped by the
 * key produced by applying {@code mapper} to the item.
 *
 * @param list the list to map
 * @param mapper the function to produce the key from a list item
 * @return the resulting map
 * @throws IllegalStateException on duplicate key
 */
public static <K, T> Map<K, T> toMapBy(List<T> list,
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> mapper) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(mapper, Function.identity()));
}
```

And here's how you would use it on a `List<Student>`:

```
Map<Long, Student> studentsById = toMapBy(students, Student::getId);
```

Comment: For a discussion of the type parameters of this method see [my follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26691278).

Comment: @EMM Of course, as intended and documented in the Javadoc.

Comment: Yes, updated the answer for covering the case of duplicates. Please review. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

A `List` and `Map` are conceptually different. A `List` is an ordered collection of items. The items can contain duplicates, and an item might not have any concept of a unique identifier (key). A `Map` has values mapped to keys. Each key can only point to one value.

Therefore, depending on your `List`'s items, it may or may not be possible to convert it to a `Map`. Does your `List`'s items have no duplicates? Does each item have a unique key? If so then it's possible to put them in a `Map`.

Answer (score 9):

There is also a simple way of doing this using [Maps.uniqueIndex(...)](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-) from Google [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) libraries

Answer (score 6):

Using java-8 streams

```java
Map<Integer, String> map = results.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> ((Integer) e[0]), e -> (String) e[1]));
```

Answer (score 5):

Universal method

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> listAsMap(Collection<V> sourceList, ListToMapConverter<K, V> converter) {
    Map<K, V> newMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
    for (V item : sourceList) {
        newMap.put( converter.getKey(item), item );
    }
    return newMap;
}

public static interface ListToMapConverter<K, V> {
    public K getKey(V item);
}
```

Comment: How to use this?  What should I pass as the `converter` parameter in the method?

Answer (score 4):

Without java-8, you'll be able to do this in one line Commons collections, and the Closure class

```java
List<Item> list;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<Key, Item> map  = new HashMap<Key, Item>>(){{
    CollectionUtils.forAllDo(list, new Closure() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Object input) {
            Item item = (Item) input;
            put(i.getKey(), item);
        }
    });
}};
```

Answer (score 4):

like already said, in java-8 we have the concise solution by Collectors:

```
  list.stream().collect(
         groupingBy(Item::getKey)
        )
```

and also, you can nest multiple group passing an other groupingBy method as second parameter:

```
  list.stream().collect(
         groupingBy(Item::getKey, groupingBy(Item::getOtherKey))
        )
```

In this way, we'll have multi level map, like this: `Map<key, Map<key, List<Item>>>`

Answer (score 3):

A Java 8 example to convert a `List<?>` of objects into a `Map<k, v>`:

```
List<Hosting> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Hosting(1, "liquidweb.com", new Date()));
list.add(new Hosting(2, "linode.com", new Date()));
list.add(new Hosting(3, "digitalocean.com", new Date()));

//example 1
Map<Integer, String> result1 = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Hosting::getId, Hosting::getName));

System.out.println("Result 1 : " + result1);

//example 2
Map<Integer, String> result2 = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getId(), x -> x.getName()));
```

Code copied from:
https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/

Answer (score 2):

Many solutions come to mind, depending on what you want to achive:

Every List item is key and value

```
for( Object o : list ) {
    map.put(o,o);
}
```

List elements have something to look them up, maybe a name:

```
for( MyObject o : list ) {
    map.put(o.name,o);
}
```

List elements have something to look them up, and there is no guarantee that they are unique: Use Googles [MultiMaps](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

```
for( MyObject o : list ) {
    multimap.put(o.name,o);
}
```

Giving all the elements the position as a key:

```
for( int i=0; i<list.size; i++ ) {
    map.put(i,list.get(i));
}
```

...

It really depends on what you want to achive.

As you can see from the examples, a Map is a mapping from a key to a value, while a list is just a series of elements having a position each. So they are simply not automatically convertible.

Comment: But we can consider List Element position as key and put their value in map, is this a good solution ?

Comment: AFAIK yes! There is no function in the JDK that does that automatically, so you have to roll your own.

Comment: is it possible to do the last version (using array index as map key) with java 8 streams?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little method I wrote for exactly this purpose.  It uses Validate from Apache Commons.

Feel free to use it.

```
/**
 * Converts a <code>List</code> to a map. One of the methods of the list is called to retrive
 * the value of the key to be used and the object itself from the list entry is used as the
 * objct. An empty <code>Map</code> is returned upon null input.
 * Reflection is used to retrieve the key from the object instance and method name passed in.
 *
 * @param <K> The type of the key to be used in the map
 * @param <V> The type of value to be used in the map and the type of the elements in the
 *            collection
 * @param coll The collection to be converted.
 * @param keyType The class of key
 * @param valueType The class of the value
 * @param keyMethodName The method name to call on each instance in the collection to retrieve
 *            the key
 * @return A map of key to value instances
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if any of the other paremeters are invalid.
 */
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> asMap(final java.util.Collection<V> coll,
        final Class<K> keyType,
        final Class<V> valueType,
        final String keyMethodName) {

    final HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
    Method method = null;

    if (isEmpty(coll)) return map;
    notNull(keyType, Messages.getString(KEY_TYPE_NOT_NULL));
    notNull(valueType, Messages.getString(VALUE_TYPE_NOT_NULL));
    notEmpty(keyMethodName, Messages.getString(KEY_METHOD_NAME_NOT_NULL));

    try {
        // return the Method to invoke to get the key for the map
        method = valueType.getMethod(keyMethodName);
    }
    catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        final String message =
            String.format(
                    Messages.getString(METHOD_NOT_FOUND),
                    keyMethodName,
                    valueType);
        e.fillInStackTrace();
        logger.error(message, e);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(message, e);
    }
    try {
        for (final V value : coll) {

            Object object;
            object = method.invoke(value);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final K key = (K) object;
            map.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        final String message =
            String.format(
                    Messages.getString(METHOD_CALL_FAILED),
                    method,
                    valueType);
        e.fillInStackTrace();
        logger.error(message, e);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(message, e);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the streams API of Java 8.

```
public class ListToMap {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> items = Arrays.asList(new User("One"), new User("Two"), new User("Three"));

    Map<String, User> map = createHashMap(items);
    for(String key : map.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(key +" : "+map.get(key));
    }
  }

  public static Map<String, User> createHashMap(List<User> items) {
    Map<String, User> map = items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, Function.identity()));
    return map;
  }
}
```

For more details visit: http://codecramp.com/java-8-streams-api-convert-list-map/

Answer (score 0):

I like Kango_V's answer, but I think it's too complex.  I think this is simpler - maybe too simple.  If inclined, you could replace String with a Generic marker, and make it work for any Key type.

```
public static <E> Map<String, E> convertListToMap(Collection<E> sourceList, ListToMapConverterInterface<E> converterInterface) {
    Map<String, E> newMap = new HashMap<String, E>();
    for( E item : sourceList ) {
        newMap.put( converterInterface.getKeyForItem( item ), item );
    }
    return newMap;
}

public interface ListToMapConverterInterface<E> {
    public String getKeyForItem(E item);
}
```

Used like this:

```
        Map<String, PricingPlanAttribute> pricingPlanAttributeMap = convertListToMap( pricingPlanAttributeList,
                new ListToMapConverterInterface<PricingPlanAttribute>() {

                    @Override
                    public String getKeyForItem(PricingPlanAttribute item) {
                        return item.getFullName();
                    }
                } );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Apache Commons MapUtils.populateMap

If you don't use Java 8 and you don't want to use a explicit loop for some reason, try `MapUtils.populateMap` from Apache Commons.

[MapUtils.populateMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html#populateMap(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer))

Say you have a list of `Pair`s.

```
List<ImmutablePair<String, String>> pairs = ImmutableList.of(
    new ImmutablePair<>("A", "aaa"),
    new ImmutablePair<>("B", "bbb")
);
```

And you now want a Map of the `Pair`'s key to the `Pair` object.

```
Map<String, Pair<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
MapUtils.populateMap(map, pairs, new Transformer<Pair<String, String>, String>() {

  @Override
  public String transform(Pair<String, String> input) {
    return input.getKey();
  }
});

System.out.println(map);
```

gives output:

```
{A=(A,aaa), B=(B,bbb)}
```

That being said, a `for` loop is maybe easier to understand. (This below gives the same output):

```
Map<String, Pair<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Pair<String, String> pair : pairs) {
  map.put(pair.getKey(), pair);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kotlin, there is an example:

```
listOf("one", "two").mapIndexed { i, it -> i to it }.toMap()
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class EmployeeDetailsFetchListToMap {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<EmployeeDetailsFetch> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new EmployeeDetailsFetch(1L, "vinay", 25000F));
    list.add(new EmployeeDetailsFetch(2L, "kohli", 5000000F));
    list.add(new EmployeeDetailsFetch(3L, "dhoni", 20000000F));

    //adding id as key and map of id and student name
    Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> map1 = list.stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                EmployeeDetailsFetch::getEmpId,
                Collectors.toMap(
                    EmployeeDetailsFetch::getEmpId,
                    EmployeeDetailsFetch::getEmployeeName
                )
            )
        );
    System.out.println(map1);

    //converting list into map of Student
    //Adding id as Key and Value as Student into a map
    Map<Long, EmployeeDetailsFetch> map = list.stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                EmployeeDetailsFetch::getEmpId, 
                EmployeeDetailsFetch -> EmployeeDetailsFetch
            )
        );

    for(Map.Entry<Long, EmployeeDetailsFetch> m : map.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println("key :" + m.getKey() + "  Value : " + m.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```