# Converting ArrayList to HashMap

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to convert List to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map)

I have arrayList

```
ArrayList<Product> productList  = new ArrayList<Product>();
 productList  = getProducts();  //Fetch the result from db
```

I want to convert to ArrayList to HashMap Like this

```
  HashMap<String, Product> s= new HashMap<String,Product>();
```

Please help me how to convert to HashMap.

Comment: Does `Product` have a unique property(ies)?

Comment: Assume that **field1** is a field within _**Product**_ class, so you can do this `Map<String, Product> urMap = yourList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getField1, Function.identity()));`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The general methodology would be to iterate through the `ArrayList`, and insert the values into the `HashMap`.  An example is as follows:

```
HashMap<String, Product> productMap = new HashMap<String, Product>();
for (Product product : productList) {
   productMap.put(product.getProductCode(), product);
}
```

Comment: Iterating is kinda slow.  There has to be a faster way.

Answer (score 1):

Using a supposed name property as the map key:

```
for (Product p: productList) { s.put(p.getName(), p); }
```

Answer (score 1):

[edited]

using your comment about productCode (and assuming product code is a String) as reference...

```
 for(Product p : productList){
        s.put(p.getProductCode() , p);
    }
```