# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Tags: java

Am new to java .getJSONValue method returns a array like this `[men,women]` and `[dog,cat]` while executing the above code 
 am getting:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   java.util.Map

```
  private Map<String, List<String>> devcap = new HashMap <String, List<String>>();
     public <T>T getJSONValue(Response res, String path ){
           String json = res.asString();
           JsonPath jpath = new JsonPath(json);
           return jpath.get(path);
     }



     devcap = helper.getJSONValue(response, "results.devices.cap");
     try {    
       for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : devcap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<String> values = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Key = " + key);
            System.out.println("Values = " + values + "n");
       }
```

How to get rid of this error

Comment: You need to iterate the ArrayList to convert it to a Map.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789527/converting-arraylist-to-hashmap

Comment: You're trying to treat something as a map, that is actually a list. You can get rid of this error by treating it like what it is: a list. So `List<Something> devcap` instead of `Map<Something> devcap`

Comment: how it can be done in my case.?coz am new to java

Comment: i changes it as `   private List<HashMap<String, List<String>>> devcap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,List<String>>>();`