# How to convert List<NameValuePair> into a hashMap<String, String>?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm capturing parameters from a request url using `com.apache.http.NameValuePair`which basically store those params in `List<NameValuePair>`. To do certain checks and verifications on those params, I need to convert that list into a `HashMap<String, String>`. Is there a way to do this conversion?

Comment: Assuming you want to make the "name" the key in the hashmap, just iterate over the list and add to the map. 

However, doing this blindly can lead to problems if the list contains a duplicate "name".  The map would end up containing only the "last" value for the duplicate key.  You need to better specify what you are trying to accomplish if you want a meaningful answer.  This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: what should the key and value be?

Comment: @JimGarrison You're right, I'm trying to make the "name" as the key. As for duplicated names, chances of that happening is almost 0. So if I iterate through the list and add it to the map, how do I specify to have 'name' as the key and 'value' (from list) as value in the map?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you use Java 8? In that case you could make use of the Collectors.toMap() method:

```
Map<String, String> mapped = list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(NameValuePair::getName, NameValuePair::getValue));
```

Otherwise you would have to loop through the elements

```
for(NameValuePair element : list) {
  //logic to convert list entries to hash map entries
}
```

To get a better understanding, please take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/convert-list-to-map/).

Comment: There is Missing closing brackets, can't add it back since it is less than 6 characters, can you help add it back in, thanks! `...NameValuePair::getValue));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it for Java 8

```
public static <K, V, T extends V> Map<K, V> toMapBy(List<T> list,
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> mapper) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(mapper, Function.identity()));
}
```

And here's how you would use it on a List:

```
Map<Long, Product> productsById = toMapBy(products, Product::getId);
```

Follow the link:

1. [Converting ArrayList to HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789527/converting-arraylist-to-hashmap)
2. [Generic static method constrains types too much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691278/generic-static-method-constrains-types-too-much?answertab=active#tab-top)
3. [Java: How to convert List to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map)

Comment: `Function.identity()` is excellent, especially when you don't type `Functions.identity()` instead