# How to convert List<NameValuePair> into a List<Map.Entry<String, String>>?

Tags: java, list, java-8

I'm capturing parameters from a request url using `com.apache.http.NameValuePair` which basically store those params in a `List<NameValuePair>`. To do certain checks and verifications on those params, I need to convert that list into a `List<Map.Entry<String, String>>`. Is there a way to do this conversion?

something like this:

http://127.0.0.1:9898/v3/{project_id}/eip/publicips?fields=id&fields=owner

from [How to convert List<NameValuePair> into a hashMap<String, String>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947858/how-to-convert-listnamevaluepair-into-a-hashmapstring-string)

```
Map<String, String> mapped = list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(NameValuePair::getName, NameValuePair::getValue));
```

It is not work for me. because there are many fields key.

Comment: Some code or example would be helpful

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert each [NameValuePair](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/NameValuePair.html) into [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) and then collect them into `List`

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = list.stream()
                                              .map(n->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>(n.getName(), n.getValue())
                                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I need to stop hurrying

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've messed something else that's not included in the code excerpt. I've tried to reproduce your case and it works in my setup.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<>();
        MyNameValuePair myNameValuePair = new MyNameValuePair();
        myNameValuePair.setKvKey("i");
        list.add(myNameValuePair);
        myNameValuePair = new MyNameValuePair();
        myNameValuePair.setKvKey("j");
        list.add(myNameValuePair);
        myNameValuePair = new MyNameValuePair();
        myNameValuePair.setKvKey("k");
        list.add(myNameValuePair);
        Map<String, String> mapped = new HashMap<>();
        mapped = list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(NameValuePair::getName, NameValuePair::getValue));

        System.out.println(mapped);
    }
}

class MyNameValuePair implements NameValuePair {
    private String kvKey;
    public void setKvKey(String kvKey){
        this.kvKey = kvKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return kvKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return "val";
    }
}
```