# Java 8 Stream function to group a List of anagrams into a Map of Lists

Tags: java, mapreduce, java-8, anagram, java-stream

Java 8 is about to be released... While learning about Streams, I got into a scenario about grouping anagrams using one of the new ways. The problem I'm facing is that I can't find a way to group Strings objects using the map/reduce functions. Instead, I had to create a similar way as documented at [Aggregate Operations - Reduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html).

Based on the documentation, we can simply use:

```java
LIST<T>.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(POJO::GET_METHOD))
```

So that `Collectors.groupingBy()` will aggregate the keys of the map based on the method used. However, this approach is too seems to be cumbersome to wrap a simple String presentation.

```java
public class AnagramsGrouping {
    static class Word {
        public String original;

        public Word(String word) {
            original = word;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            char[] characters = input.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(characters);
            return new String(characters);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return original;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Word> words = Arrays.asList(new Word("pool"), new Word("loop"),
                new Word("stream"), new Word("arc"), new Word("odor"),
                new Word("car"), new Word("rood"), new Word("meats"),
                new Word("fires"), new Word("fries"), new Word("night"),
                new Word("thing"), new Word("mates"), new Word("teams"));

        Map<String, List<Word>> anagrams = words.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Word::getKey));

        System.out.println(anagrams);
    }
}
```

This prints the following:

```
{door=[odor, rood], acr=[arc, car], ghint=[night, thing],
 aemrst=[stream], efirs=[fires, fries], loop=[pool, loop],
 aemst=[meats, mates, teams]}
```

Instead, I'm looking for a simpler and more direct solution that uses the new map/reduce functions to accumulate the results into the similar interface `Map<String, List<String>`. Based on [How to convert List to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887747/433814), I have the following:

```java
List<String> words2 = Arrays.asList("pool", "loop", "stream", "arc",
        "odor", "car", "rood", "meats", "fires", "fries",
        "night", "thing", "mates", "teams");

words2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> sortChars(w), w -> w));
```

But this code generates a key collision as it is a Map of 1-1.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key pool
```

which makes sense... Is there a way to group them into the similar output as the first solution with `groupingBy`, but without using a POJO wrapping the values?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The single-argument `groupingBy` collector does exactly what you want to do. It classifies its input, which you've already done using `sortChars` (or `getKey` in the earlier example). Each stream value that's classified under the same key gets put into a list which is the map's value. Thus we have:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams =
    words2.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> sortChars(w)));
```

giving the output

```
{door=[odor, rood], acr=[arc, car], ghint=[night, thing], aemrst=[stream],
efirs=[fires, fries], loop=[pool, loop], aemst=[meats, mates, teams]}
```

You could also use a method reference:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams =
    words2.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GroupingAnagrams::sortChars));
```

If you want to do something with the values other than building up a list, use a multi-arg overload of `groupingBy` and a "downstream" collector. For example, to count the words instead of building up a list, do this:

```
Map<String, Long> anagrams =
    words2.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(GroupingAnagrams::sortChars, Collectors.counting()));
```

This results in:

```
{door=2, acr=2, ghint=2, aemrst=1, efirs=2, loop=2, aemst=3}
```

**EDIT:**

In case it wasn't clear, `sortChars` is simply a static function that performs a similar function to what `getKey` did in the first example, but from string to string:

```
public static String sortChars(String input) {
    char[] characters = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(characters);
    return new String(characters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) method with four parameters and specify separately: the key type, the value type, the merge function for values with the same key, and the particular implementation of the `Map` into which the results will be inserted.

In this case, you can choose:

- key - `int[]` - a sorted array of character code points of the word;
- value - `List<String>` - a list of anagrams;
- merge function - two lists into one;
- map - `TreeMap` with a comparator that compares two `int[]` arrays.

```java
List<String> words = List.of("pool", "loop", "stream", "arc", "odor", "car",
        "rood", "meats", "fires", "fries", "night", "thing", "mates", "teams");
```

```java
Map<int[], List<String>> anagrams = words.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // key - a sorted array of character code points
                word -> word.codePoints().sorted().toArray(),
                // value - a list of anagrams
                word -> new ArrayList<>(List.of(word)),
                // merge elements of two lists
                (list1, list2) -> {
                    list1.addAll(list2);
                    return list1;
                },
                // comparator that compares two int[] arrays
                () -> new TreeMap<>(Arrays::compare)));
```

```java
// output
anagrams.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(v.get(0) + "=" + v));
```

Output:

```
arc=[arc, car]
stream=[stream]
meats=[meats, mates, teams]
odor=[odor, rood]
fires=[fires, fries]
night=[night, thing]
pool=[pool, loop]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How do you check if a word has an anagram that is a palindrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67082201/15613375)</sup>