# How can I check if two strings are anagrams?

Tags: java, arrays, string, project, anagram

**These are the details of my project:**
Anagrams: The aim of this project is to create a game in which the user is presented with
an anagram of a word and has to guess the right word within a limited number of
attempts.
Features of the Project:

1. The user is given a fixed number of attempts to guess the correct word. The number
   of attempts is dependent on the length of the word.
2. After each incorrect attempt the user is provided with a hint of the correct word.
3. If the user is not able to guess the right word within the fixed number of attempts the
   correct word is displayed and the game moves on to the next word.
4. Give controls for exiting the game.

**Problems I am facing:**

I was able to take a random word from an array of strings but wasn't able to compare that to the output as the output is a normal string. I would like to know how to fix this and also how should I proceed further, I don't need the answer for the hint part just want to know how can I compare 2 types of strings.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class main {
    String A = "words[index]";

    static boolean isAnagram(String A, String B) {
        if (A.length() != B.length()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            char a[] = A.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            char b[] = A.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

            Arrays.sort(a);
            Arrays.sort(b);
            String sortedA = String.valueOf(a);
            String sortedB = String.valueOf(B);
            if (sortedA.equals(sortedB)) {
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = {"Rat", "Car", "Below", "Taste", "Cried", "Study", "Thing", "Chin"};
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(words.length);
        System.out.println("The given word is: " + words[index]);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String B = sc.next();
        if (isAnagram(String A, String B)) {
            System.out.println("not an angram");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sucess");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer two methods for checking whether two strings are anagrams:

1.

```java
static boolean isAnagram(String A, String B) {
    if (A.length() != B.length()) return false;
    else {
        char[] a = A.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] b = A.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(a);
        Arrays.sort(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;
        return true; //time Complexity: O(nLogn)
    }
}
```

2. 

```java
static int NUM_OF_CHARS = 256;

static boolean isAnagram(String A, String B) {
    if (A.length() != B.length()) return false;
    else {
        int[] count1 = new int[NUM_OF_CHARS];
        Arrays.fill(count1, 0);
        int[] count2 = new int[NUM_OF_CHARS];
        Arrays.fill(count2, 0);
        char[] a = A.toCharArray();
        char[] b = A.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++) {
            count1[a[i]]++;
            count2[b[i]]++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CHARS; i++)
            if (count1[i] != count2[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }//time Complexity: O(n)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get two arrays of characters from these strings, sort them, and then check if these arrays are equal to each other.

```java
/**
 * @param a first string.
 * @param b second string.
 * @return whether two strings are case insensitive anagrams of each other.
 */
static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    // invalid incoming data
    if (a == null || b == null
            || a.length() != b.length()) return false;
    return Arrays.equals(
            a.toLowerCase().codePoints().sorted().toArray(),
            b.toLowerCase().codePoints().sorted().toArray());
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isAnagram("Study", "dusty")); // true
    System.out.println(isAnagram("door", "rooD"));   // true
    System.out.println(isAnagram("door", "root"));   // false
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Java 8 Stream function to group a List of anagrams into a Map of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67099938/15675591)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Check whether two strings are anagram or not using collections:

```java
package StringPackage;
import java.util.*;

public class AnagramUsingCollections {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char[] string1 = "aab".toCharArray();
        char[] string2 = "baa".toCharArray();

        Map<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        for (char no : string1) {
            //for start
            Integer count = hm.get(no);
            if (count == null) {
                hm.put(no, 1);
            } else {
                count++;
                hm.put(no, count);
            }
            //for end
        }
        if (string1.length == string2.length) {
            for (char no : string2) {
                //baa
                Integer count = hm.get(no);
                if (count == null) {
                    hm.put(no, 1);
                } else {
                    count--;
                    hm.put(no, count);
                }
            }//for end
        }
        Set<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> se = hm.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> me : se) {
            if (me.getValue() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Not an anagram");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("IS an anagram");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isAnagram = function(s, t) {
    if (s.length !== t.length) {
        return false; // Different lengths cannot be anagrams
    }
    const sCount = {};
    const tCount = {};
    
    s.split("").forEach(letter => {
        sCount[letter] = (sCount[letter] || 0) + 1;
    });
    
    t.split("").forEach(letter => {
        tCount[letter] = (tCount[letter] || 0) + 1;
    });
    // Check if all keys and values in tCount are present in sCount
    for (const key in tCount) {
        if (!(key in sCount) || sCount[key] !== tCount[key]) {
            return false; // Found a key that is missing or has a different count
        }
    }

    return true; // All keys and values are the same in both objects
};
```

Comment: The question is tagged "java" and the code in the question is Java code, however it appears that you have posted JavaScript code. I don't think JavaScript code will help the OP. I suggest that you [edit] your answer and post Java code - but only if your answer adds something that is not already present in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

For strings with only letters, you can just use an array with 26 elements.

```java
public static boolean isAnagram(String one, String two) {
    if (one.length() != two.length())
        return false;

    int[] arr = new int[26];
    countLetters(arr, one, true);
    countLetters(arr, two, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] != 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

private static void countLetters(int[] arr, String str, boolean add) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int offs = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)) - 'a';
        arr[offs] += add ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```