# Generic static method constrains types too much

Tags: java, generics, java-8

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26594540) I attempted to create a static utility method to make a `List` into a `Map`:

```
public static <K, T> Map<K, T> toMapBy(List<T> list,
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> mapper) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(mapper, Function.identity()));
}
```

It works just fine. However, I found that the method cannot be used in all the same contexts as the `list.stream().collect(...)` expression. The method isn't as flexible.

```
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList();

Map<Long, Student> studentsById1 = students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getId, Function.identity()));
Map<Long, Student> studentsById2 = toMapBy(students, Student::getId);

Map<Long, Person> peopleById1 = students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getId, Function.identity()));
Map<Long, Person> peopleById2 = toMapBy(students, Student::getId);  // compile error!
```

In this example, `Student` is a subtype of `Person` and has a `getId` method that returns a `Long`.

The last statement fails with `incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds ...` (JDK 1.8.0_25). Is there a way to define the type parameters so that the static method will work in the same contexts as the expression it contains?

Comment: [is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p). `Map<Long, Person>` can't be reference to returned `Map<Long, Student>`. Maybe consider using `Map<Long, ? extends Person>` as reference.

Comment: If you could use `Map<Long, Person>` reference for instance of `Map<Long, Student>` it would mean that via such reference you could put to this map any kind of person, not only Student (in other words generics are not covariant).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a type parameter for the values of the map so they can be different from T:

```
public static <K, V, T extends V> Map<K, V> toMapBy(List<T> list,
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> mapper) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(mapper, Function.identity()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last line calls the method `toMapBy` in which the compiler infers the type `Student` for `T`. So it obviously returns a `List<Long, Student>`.

[*But generics aren't covariant!*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant)

That means, you cannot assign a `List<Long, Student>` to a variable of type `List<Long, Person>`, because they are not in a subtype relationship.

The solution is to use the subtype form:

```
Map<Long, ? extends Person> peopleById2 = toMapBy(students, Student::getId); // no compiler error
```

Comment: True, but the question is whether it's possible to define `toMapBy`'s type parameters so that it will work in the same contexts as the stream expression. In other words, why can `Map<Long, Person>` be the assignment target in the second to last line but not in the last?

Comment: Interesting. But look as @Alex' answer. This is _the_ solution.

Answer (score 0):

With this bit:

```
Map<Long, Person> peopleById1 = students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getId, Function.identity()));
```

Notice that you do not provide arguments to `Function.identity()`. The compiler is free to infer it as `Function.<Person>identity()` to resolve the difference imposed by the return value assignment.

This should be good enough for your purpose:

```
public static <K, T> Map<K, T> toMapBy(
    List<? extends T> list, // <- note
    Function<? super T, ? extends K> mapper
) {
    ...
}
```

Now the elements of the List can be a subtype of the Map values. Or you can define a third parameter like @Alex has suggested.