# How to add List of objects in a Map

Tags: java, collections

I have a List and A is defined below.

How do i add in a Map with Key as Long and values as List of Strings.

```
Class A
{
Long in;
List<String> out;
}
Map<Long,List<String>>
```

Comment: Using `map.put(key, value)`.

Comment: `map.put(a.in, a.out);`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to convert List to Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Hashmap` object, with key `Long` and value `List`. Add items with `put(key,value)` and retrieve them with `get`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Long,List<String>> myMap=new HashMap<Long,List<String>>();
        List<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("abc");
        myList.add("xyz");
        myMap.put(new Long(1), myList);
        for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++)
            System.out.println(myMap.get(new Long(1)).get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create HashMap with `Key as Long` and `value as List<String>`.

2.) Use `put method` of HashMap, as below.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Long, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();
        myMap.put(101L, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
```