# Why does Function.identity() break type reification but t -> t does not?

Tags: java, generics, reification

Answers found at [Java 8 lambdas, Function.identity() or t->t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28032827/14731) seem to imply that `Function.identity()` is almost always equivalent to `t -> t`. However, in the testcase seen below, replacing `t -> t` by `Function.identity()` results in a compiler error. Why is that?

```
public class Testcase {

    public static <T, A, R, K, V> Collector<T, A, R> comparatorOrdering(
            Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
            Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper,
            Comparator<? super K> keyComparator,
            Comparator<? super V> valueComparator) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Map<Integer, String> case1 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).
                collect(comparatorOrdering(t -> t, t -> String.valueOf(t),
                        Comparator.naturalOrder(), Comparator.naturalOrder()));
        Map<Integer, String> case2 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).
                collect(comparatorOrdering(Function.identity(), t -> String.valueOf(t),
                        Comparator.naturalOrder(), Comparator.naturalOrder()));
    }
}
```

Case 1 compiles just fine but case 2 fails with:

```
method comparatorOrdering in class Testcase cannot be applied to given types;
                collect(comparatorOrdering(Function.identity(), t -> String.valueOf(t),
  required: Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Function<? super T#1,? extends V>,Comparator<? super K>,Comparator<? super V>
  found: Function<Object,Object>,(t)->Strin[...]Of(t),Comparator<T#2>,Comparator<T#3>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: Object
    upper bound(s): Comparable<? super T#4>,T#4,Object
  where T#1,A,R,K,V,T#2,T#3,T#4 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,A,R,K,V>comparatorOrdering(Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Function<? super T#1,? extends V>,Comparator<? super K>,Comparator<? super V>)
    A extends Object declared in method <T#1,A,R,K,V>comparatorOrdering(Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Function<? super T#1,? extends V>,Comparator<? super K>,Comparator<? super V>)
    R extends Object declared in method <T#1,A,R,K,V>comparatorOrdering(Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Function<? super T#1,? extends V>,Comparator<? super K>,Comparator<? super V>)
    K extends Object declared in method <T#1,A,R,K,V>comparatorOrdering(Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Function<? super T#1,? extends V>,Comparator<? super K>,Comparator<? super V>)
    V extends Object declared in method <T#1,A,R,K,V>comparatorOrdering(Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Function<? super T#1,? extends V>,Comparator<? super K>,Comparator<? super V>)
    T#2 extends Comparable<? super T#2>
    T#3 extends Comparable<? super T#3>
    T#4 extends Comparable<? super T#4> declared in method <T#4>naturalOrder()
```

My environment is Windows 10, 64-bit, Oracle JDK build 1.8.0_92-b14.

**UPDATE**: Seeing as this compiles under ecj, I have a follow-up question: Is this a bug in `javac`? What does the JLS have to say about this case?

Comment: Can you share some details about your env? This compiles just fine on mine.

Comment: I can reproduce this with Java 1.8.0_92.  (OpenJDK)

Comment: @StephenC which build of 1.8.0_92? I'm using 1.8.0_92-b14 and can't reproduce.

Comment: `$ java -version` ==> `openjdk version "1.8.0_92"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)` .... On Fedora Linux

Comment: The error is reproduceable in javac not in ecj, so no error in eclipse doesnt say much.

Answer (score 5):

Ecj is able to infere the correct(?) type argument (Integer) to match the constraints. Javac for some reason comes to a different result.

Thats not the first time javac/ecj behave differently in inference of type parameters.

In that case you can give javac a hint with Function.<Integer>identity() to make it compileable with javac.

For the difference between Function.identity() and t->t:

- Function.identity() is Function<T,T>
- t->t in that case is Function<? super Integer, ? extends Integer>

So t->t is more flexible in the methods it can match to.

Comment: it compiles fine with `javac 1.8.0_60` after specifying type Integer

Comment: I added a follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `i -> i` and `Function.identity()` is apparent in situation where (1) collectors are nested and (2) *upcast* is needed somewhere in deep level of nesting.

Example: Suppose we are to classify elements in `List<Object>` into map with particular lists by element class. (It resembles [Guava ClassToInstanceMap](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/latest/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) except the value is `List`, so something like hypothetical `ClassToInstanceMultimap`.) The downstream collector `toList()` normally collects values into `List<Object>`. However, if the value type of map is wildcard type `List<?>`, type inference cannot simply match it. The solution is to adapt collector to pretend it collects `List<?>`, which is done by intermediate `collectingAndThen` collector.

The point is now, what should the finisher function look like? Lambda `i -> i` behaves like `Function<List<Object>, List<?>>`, which allows upcast. `Function.identity()` with fixed input and output type `T` gives no room for upcast we need, hence code won't compile.

```java
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Apple {}
    class Pear {}
    List<Object> list = List.of(new Apple(), new Pear(), new Apple());
    Map<Class<?>, List<Object>> obj;  
    obj = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Object::getClass, toList())); // compiles
    Map<Class<?>, List<?>> wild;
    wild = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Object::getClass, toList())); // wont compile
    wild = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Object::getClass, collectingAndThen(toList(), i -> i)));  // compiles
    wild = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Object::getClass, collectingAndThen(toList(), identity())));  // wont compile
    wild = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Object::getClass, collectingAndThen(toList(), (List<Object> i) -> (List<?>)i)));  // compiles
    System.out.println(wild);
}
```

Comment: I know that you're trying to help but your answer doesn't actually answer the question. I know that `i -> i` is behaving differently than `Function.identity()` but what makes you believe that it should? Does the JLS specify that `i -> i` is supposed to allow upcasts? A reference would be helpful.