# Java Streams: Override return type of Collectors.mapping

Tags: java, java-stream

This is my code:

```java
Map<String, Collection<? extends String>> test = listOfTipusIdentificadorPacient.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        TipusIdentificadorPacient::getOid,
        Collectors.mapping(TipusIdentificadorPacient::getUse, Collectors.toList())
    )
);
```

I'm getting this compilation message:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,List> to Map<String,Collection<? extends String>>

I don't quite figure out how to override `Collectors.mapping` in order to:

```
return:
  Map<String,Collection<? extends String>>
instead of:
  Map<String,List<String>>
```

I've tried to create another generic code in order to make it to compile.

Code is:

```java
Stream<Map.Entry<String, String>> streamOfPairedStrings = Stream.of();
Map<String, Collection<? extends String>> test = streamOfPairedStrings
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.mapping(Pair::getValue, Collectors.toList())
    )
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Map<String, List<String>>` isn't a `Map<String, Collection<? extends String>>`, it's a `Map<String, ? extends Collection<? extends String>>`.

Comment: You can add, say, a value `Set<String>` to a `Map<String, Collection<? extends String>>`. You can't add a value `Set<String>` to a `Map<String, List<String>>`. That's why it's not compiling.

Comment: `Map<String, Collection<? extends String>> map = listOfTipusIdentificadorPacient.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TipusIdentificadorPacient::getOid,
                        Collectors.mapping(TipusIdentificadorPacient::getUse, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), x -> x)))
);`

Comment: @Jordi, I found this explanation (answer with 1 upvote): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034982/why-does-function-identity-break-type-reification-but-t-t-does-not

Comment: What is the purpose of declaring it `Collection<? extends String>` instead of `Collection<String>`?

Comment: There is no such thing as <? extends String>. It's a `final` class. No point in that part of your type specification.

Comment: @user207421 except that it provides compile-time protection against adding anything other than literal null to the collection. Which is, iunno, maybe useful, somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the compilation error is thus:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists = Map.of();
Map<String, Collection<? extends String>> mapOfCollections = Map.of();
```

Consider that this code would then be legal:

```
mapOfCollections.put("", Set.of());
```

That is, you can put key/value pairs where the value isn't a `List<String>`. As such, you can't assign:

```
mapOfCollections = mapOfLists;
```

because then you could do the `put` above, leading to heap pollution. The compiler just stops you doing it.

```
// If it were legal...
mapOfCollections = mapOfLists;
mapOfCollections.put("", Set.of());
List<String> list = mapOfLists.get(""); // ClassCastException!
```

---

I think you could do this with `Collectors.collectingAndThen` around the `toList()`, where the "and then" is an unconstrained cast:

```
Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), a -> a)
```

The reason you can't do this with `Function.identity()` is the combination of the signature of `collectingAndThen` and `Function.identity()`:

- `collectingAndThen(Collector<T,A,R> downstream, Function<R,RR> finisher)` means that the input type of the function has to match the output type of the collector - in your case, `List<String>`.
- `Function.identity()` is a `Function<T, T>` (with no wildcards). Since the input type of the function has to be `List<String>`, its output type is also `List<String>`.

`a -> a` *looks like* the identity function, but it's actually more generic than that: it's an upcast function, `Function<? extends T, T>`, meaning the output type doesn't have to be exactly the same as the input, but it's something that can be cast safely.

Thus, here, `a -> a` acts as a `Function<List<String>, Collection<? extends String>>` (because `List<String>` is a subtype of `Collection<String>`, which is a subtype of `Collection<? extends String>`).

Comment: I'm using java 11. `mappingAndthen` is nt available...

Comment: @Jordi It's `collectingAndThen`, not `mappingAndThen`. AndyTurner, I suggest you write the full line of code as it seems confusing for OP.

Comment: I've edited post. I've created a generic code could be useful to be compilable. I mean, I've removed business classes. Could you make last code to be compilable?

Comment: I've tried to use `Function.identity()` instead of `a -> a`. Nevertheless, something goes broken. Do you think it could be possible to use `Function.identity` elegantly here instead?

Comment: @Jordi I've edited to add more details about why your original code doesn't work, and also why `identity()` doesn't work.