# Why can't I replace (t -> t) with Function.identity() in the argument to Optional.filter?

Tags: java, java-8

I have some code that looks a bit like this (it's simplified here):

```
public Optional<String> parseInput(String input){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    return Optional.of(matcher.find())
                   .filter(t -> t) // .filter(Function.identity())
                   .map(ignore -> matcher.group(1));
}
```

But it fails with an error:

> `Error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that 
>   java.util.function.Function<T,T> conforms to java.util.function.Predicate<? 
>   super java.lang.Boolean>`

What is going on here, and why is it designed this way?

Comment: `filter` expects a predicate that returns a boolean. `Function.identity()` doesn't do that. Don't think it works in the `Stream` filter either

Comment: I didn't actually check that it works with `Stream`, but I made the assumption after coming across [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t) while trying to find an answer.

Comment: `Functon.identity()` returns as object of type `Function`, but `filter` wants an object of type `Predicate`

Comment: Right, I see now. Java won't let you define `Predicate<T>` to be an alias for `Function<T, Boolean>`.

Comment: You could use `Boolean::booleanValue`

Comment: Had to test it .... It also doesn't work in a `Stream` filter. Not even with a `Stream<Boolean>`. As you said, Java won't let you use a Function as a Predicate

Comment: @RobinTopper I have tested it and you are right. I'm now confused about this question: [Java 8 lambdas, Function.identity() or t->t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t)

Comment: It is used in various map operators in that question and the answers. And those do take a Function.

Comment: Yep. That makes sense. `filter` is more constrained than `map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summarising the comments, I can answer my own question.

`Predicate<T>` is unrelated to `Function<T, Boolean>`, and they can't be used in each other's place, even if it would often appear to make logical sense.

`Predicate<T>` likely exists because there are times when you might want to compose predicates using the methods: `and`, `or` and `negate`, and these methods just wouldn't makes sense on `Function<T, U>`. Java does not permit methods to be defined only for a subset of the possible generic parameters, so predicates are more ergonomically modeled by `Predicate<T>` rather than `Function<T, Boolean>` for common use-cases.

Another reason for having a separate interface for predicates is that Java does not permit primitives in generic parameters. That means you cannot define a predicate as `Function<T, boolean>` — it would have to be `Function<T, Boolean>`, so a caller of the predicate would have to handle the possibility of `null` return values. Using a specialized interface allows the return value of `test` to be a `boolean` instead and allows callers to assume the result is never `null` .

A possible replacement in my original use case is `Boolean::booleanValue`, which can be used where either `Predicate<Boolean>` or `Function<Boolean, Boolean>` is required.

Comment: There is another advantage of `Predicate<T>` over `Function<T,Boolean>` for the intended use case: the caller of `Predicate.test` does not have to deal with `null` results.

Comment: @Holger Good observation! I'll add that.

Answer (score 7):

The main issue here is in an incorrect type. A `Predicate` is not a `Function`, it is not a subinterface of a `Function`, but rather an *independent* functional interface. `Stream#filter` accepts a `Predicate` as parameter: `filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`. Since there is no relation between `Predicate` and `Function`, we can't use `Function` with `filter`.

What might be confusing in this case, is that even if `t -> t` looks exactly like `Function.identity()` or just `Function`, it might not be a `Function`. An important thing to remember about lambda expressions is that a lambda itself doesn't contain any information about its type. That information is deduced from the context. The same lambda can represent different functional interfaces.

```
Predicate<Boolean> predicate = t -> t;
Function<Boolean,Boolean> function = t -> t;

Predicate<Boolean> predicateBoolean = Boolean::booleanValue;
Function<Boolean,Boolean> functionBoolean = Boolean::booleanValue;
```