# How to use :: operator as this reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Converting a list of objects `Foo` having an `id`, to a `Map<Integer,Foo>` with that `id` as key, is easy using the stream API:

```
public class Foo{
    private Integer id;
    private ....
    getters and setters...
}

Map<Integer,Foo> myMap = 
fooList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, (foo) -> foo));
```

Is there any way to substitute the lambda expression: `(foo) -> foo` with something using the `::` operator? Something like `Foo::this`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it's not a method reference, `Function.identity()` is what you need:

```
Map<Integer,Foo> myMap = 
    fooList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, Function.identity()));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've tried to find and aswer without success, but it seems to be a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Function.identity()` to replace a `foo -> foo` lambda.

---

If you really want to demostrate a method reference, you can write a meaningless method

```
class Util {
    public static <T> T identity(T t) { return t; }
}
```

and refer to it by the method reference `Util::identity`:

```
( ... ).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, Util::identity));
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between `Function.identity()` and `x -> x` as very good explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t), but sometimes I favor the second; it's less verbose and when the pipeline is complicate I tend to use: `x -> x`