# How efficiently we can get the required output from the list in java?

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8

```
CircuitID   Department  Hours

--------------------------------

Circuit A   Electricity      60

Circuit A   Hydel            70

Circuit B   Hydel            30

Circuit C   Electricity      40

Circuit B   Electricity      80

Circuit C   Hydel            50

Circuit A   Electricity      70
```

Now i have to create one list which will have records on following criteria:

1. In each circuit id i need to get the record with highest hours but if duplicate hours are present than i need to take the one with Electricity department.

Result for the above result should be like below:

```
Circuit A  Electricity   70

Circuit B  Electricity   80

Circuit C  Hydel          50
```

Let me know how can i iterate effectively and in most efficient way to get the final list using java 8/ java.

The code i wrote is not at all working perfectly and my approch was shown below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < circuitList.size(); i++) {

  for (int j = 0; j < circuitList.size(); {
    if (circuitList.get(i).getCircuitId().equals(circuitList.get(j).getCircuitId()) && i != j) {



     if (circuitList().get(i).getHours() == circuitList().get(j).getHours()) {



      if (circuitList().get(i).getDepartment().equals(“Electricity”) {



        newList.add(circuitList().get(i));

        }

        // some more conditions on getHours
```

Circuit class is having pojo objects with getter setters of this three objects.

```
 public class Circuit {

        String circuitID;
        int hours;
        String department;
}
```

Comment: Please, show what the `Circuit` class looks like. Also, it'd be nice if you corrected typos like `getCircuitId`, `getCircuitId()`, `“Electricity”`, `circuitList()` along with indents and closing braces

Comment: Use a `groupingBy` to `collect` by circuit. Use a downstream of `maxBy` with a collector sorting first on hours then on type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Map<String, Circuit> getMaxHours(final List<Circuit> circuitsList) {
    final Map<String, Circuit> mappedCircuitsById = new HashMap<String, Circuit>();

    for (final Circuit circuit : circuitsList) {
        if (!mappedCircuitsById.containsKey(circuit.getCircuitID())) {
            mappedCircuitsById.put(circuit.getCircuitID(), circuit);
        } else {
            final Circuit existingMax = mappedCircuitsById.get(circuit.getCircuitID());
            if (circuit.getHours() > existingMax.getHours()) mappedCircuitsById.put(circuit.getCircuitID(), circuit);
            else if (circuit.getHours() == existingMax.getHours()) {
                if (circuit.getDepartment().equals("Electricity")) mappedCircuitsById.put(circuit.getCircuitID(), circuit);
                else if (existingMax.getDepartment().equals("Electricity")) mappedCircuitsById.put(circuit.getCircuitID(), existingMax);
            }
        }
    }

    return mappedCircuitsById;
}
```

Create a map where the key of the map is the `circuitID` and the value is the `Circuit` object which meets the "max hours" requirements. Iterate over the elements of the list and and update the map accordingly to store the new "max hours" `Circuit` object

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by `toMap()` collectors with merge function.

```
Map<String, Circuit> map = circuitList
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Circuit::getCircuitID, Function.identity(),merge));
```

and merge function is:

```
BinaryOperator<Circuit> merge = (left, right) -> {
        if (left.hours > right.hours) return left;
        else if (left.hours < right.hours) return right;
        //if (left.department.equals("Electricity")) return left;
        if (right.department.equals("Electricity")) return right;
        return left;
};
```

and get final result:

```
List<Circuit> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Comment: You can remove the `if (left.department.equals("Electricity")) return left;` check altogether.

Comment: Why not just `maxBy`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, Yeah I thought about it too. `Comparator<Circuit> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Circuit::getHours)
                .thenComparingInt(circuit -> circuit.circuitID.equals("Electricity")?1:-1);` and  then `Map<String, Optional<Circuit>> map =  circuitList
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Circuit::getCircuitID,Collectors.maxBy(comparator)));`

Comment: Your comparator is wrong as it never returns `0`  - but yeah, something like that.

Comment: When i tried your solution i get List as `[CircuitProblem.Circuit@1a71e93, CircuitProblem.Circuit@6cbb7a, CircuitProblem.Circuit@3df479]` , i can get them in correct format when i override toString() in my Circuit class, but is there a way i can do it without overriding .toString() ??

Comment: @Joka Lee `result.forEach(circuit->System.out.printLn("[CircuitID: "+circuit.circuitID+ " Department  :" + circuit.department + " Hours : "+ circuit.hours +"]"));`

Comment: In previous many answers you have used function.identity() , what is the advantage of it over s->s ?? Any resource ??

Comment: @JokaLee, I think it is more readable than `s->s`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t)

Answer (score 3):

First write a custom comparator to check for highest hours and evaluate duplicate hours situation to take the one with `Electricity` department:

```
Comparator<Circuit> cmp = new Comparator<Circuit>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Circuit o1, Circuit o2) {
        
        int compare = Integer.compare(o1.getHours(), o2.getHours());
        
        if(compare==0) {  // equal hours so check for department

            // the element with 'Electricity' value must seem to be have max value
            if(o1.getDepartment().equals("Electricity")) {
                compare = 1;
            }
            if(o2.getDepartment().equals("Electricity")) {
                compare = -1;
            }
        }
        
        return compare;
    }
};
```

Then group by `circuitId` attribute with `Collectors.groupingBy(Circuit::getCircuitId,`  and find max hours with the help of custom comparator above `Collectors.maxBy(cmp)`:

```
Map<String, Optional<Circuit>> resultMap = circuitList.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Circuit::getCircuitId, Collectors.maxBy(cmp)));
Collection<Optional<Circuit>> result = resultMap.values();
result.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.get().getCircuitId() + "  " + x.get().getDepartment() + "\t" + x.get().getHours()));
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to group by CircuitID first and write custom comparator to filter based on our requirement. It can be done as shown below:

```
List<Circuits> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Circuits::getCircuitID)).forEach((key, value) -> filteredList.add(compare(value)));


private static Circuits compare (List<Circuits> list) {
    Circuits circuits = null;
    for (Circuits c : list) {
        if (null == circuits) {
            circuits = c;
        }
        if (c.getHours() > circuits.getHours()) {
            circuits = c;
        } else if (c.getHours() == circuits.getHours()) {
            circuits = c.getDepartment().equalsIgnoreCase("Electricity") ? c : circuits;
        }
    }
    return circuits;
}
```