# In Java why is Function.identity() a static method instead of something else?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, functional-interface

Java 8 added functional programming constructs, including the `Function` class and its associated `identity()` method.

Here's the current structure of this method:

```
// Current implementation of this function in the [JDK source][1]
static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
    return t -> t;
}

// Can be used like this
List<T> sameList = list.stream().map(Function.identity()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, there's a second way to structure it:

```
// Alternative implementation of the method
static <T> T identity(T in) {
    return in;
}

// Can be used like this
List<T> sameList = list.stream().map(Function::identity).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There's even a third way to structure it:

```
// Third implementation
static final Function<T, T> IDENTITY_FUNCTION = t -> t;

// Can be used like this
List<T> sameList = list.stream().map(Function.IDENTITY_FUNCTION).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of the three approaches, the first one that is actually used in the JDK looks less memory efficient, as it appears to be creating a new object (lambda) on every use, while the second and third implementations don't. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041480/872425) that's not actually the case, so ultimately all three approaches seem relatively equivalent performance-wise.

Using the second approach allows the method to be used as a method reference, which is similar to how many other standard library methods are used in functional constructs. E.g. `stream.map(Math::abs)` or `stream.map(String::toLowerCase)`.

Overall, why use the first approach, which *looks* (though ultimately isn't) less performant and is different from other examples?

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't think they're saying that those are the same, but rather thay for the given implementation (identity as a function with signature `T(T)`), that would be the way to use it.

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your question.

Comment: Did you _try_ your "third implementation"?

Comment: `static int Math.abs(int)` and `String String::toLowerCase()` predate lambdas, so it couldn't be changed, besides those methods can also be called directly, instead of only as method references. In contrast, `<T> T Function::identity(T in)` would be new, and nobody would ever call it directly (what would be the point?).

Comment: You kind of mentioned style used for streams so it may be worth pointing that despite not being specified anywhere officially, we are *encouraged* to use static imports for methods which *provide* implementations of functional interfaces. So instead of `Collectors.toList()` we could write `toList()`, instead of `Comparator.compare(..)` `compare(...)`. This allows streams to be written like `.map(String::length).collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()));`. In that example IMO simple `identity()` is simpler than `Function::identity` which you mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***TL;DR*** Using `Function.identity()` creates only one object, so it's very memory efficient.

---

Third implementation doesn't compile, because `T` is undefined, so that's not an option.

In second implementation, every time you write `Function::identity` a **new** object instance is created.

In first implementation, whenever you call `Function.identity()`, an instance to the **same** lambda object is returned.

It is simple to see for yourself. Start by creating the two `identity` methods in the same class, so rename them to `identity1` and `identity2` to keep them separately identifiable.

```
static <T> Function<T, T> identity1() {
    return t -> t;
}

static <T> T identity2(T in) {
    return in;
}
```

Write a `test` method that accepts a `Function` and prints the object, so we can see it's unique identity, as reflected by the hash code.

```
static <A, B> void test(Function<A, B> func) {
    System.out.println(func);
}
```

Call the `test` method repeatedly to see if each one gets a new object instance or not *(my code is in a class named `Test`)*.

```
test(Test.identity1());
test(Test.identity1());
test(Test.identity1());
test(Test::identity2);
test(Test::identity2);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    test(Test::identity2);
```

*Output*

```
Test$$Lambda$1/0x0000000800ba0840@7adf9f5f
Test$$Lambda$1/0x0000000800ba0840@7adf9f5f
Test$$Lambda$1/0x0000000800ba0840@7adf9f5f
Test$$Lambda$2/0x0000000800ba1040@5674cd4d
Test$$Lambda$3/0x0000000800ba1440@65b54208
Test$$Lambda$4/0x0000000800ba1840@6b884d57
Test$$Lambda$4/0x0000000800ba1840@6b884d57
Test$$Lambda$4/0x0000000800ba1840@6b884d57
```

As you can see, multiple *statements* calling `Test.identity1()` all get the same object, but multiple *statements* using `Test::identity2` all get different objects.

It is true that *repeated* executions of the *same* statement gets the same object (as seen in result from the loop), but that's different from result obtained from *different* statements.

***Conclusion:*** Using `Test.identity1()` creates only one object, so it's more memory efficient than using `Test::identity2`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the method reference creates a new object each time? And is that required by the language spec or is it an artifact of Oracle's JVM (or whatever JVM you were testing on)?

Comment: @Mark I don't think there is anything in the spec about that. The fact that a particular written method reference creates a single reusable lambda object on first use is a JVM implementation decision. The implementation of `Function.identity()` in Oracles API simply relies on that. Other implementations might not have the JVM do it, in which case they might implement `Function.identity()` to do such memoization itself.

Comment: That’s explained in [Does a lambda expression create an object on the heap every time it's executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/2711488), but as said in [Is method reference caching a good idea in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23991339/2711488), if a particular implementation does not reuse the object produced for a stateless lambda, it must have a reason for that and we shouldn’t counteract, in other words, a `Function.identity()` doing memoization itself would be a questionable thing.

Comment: As a fun fact, [`Objects.isNull(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) does not follow the pattern of `Function.identity()`, but rather is intended to be used as `Object::isNull`. It has been added in the same release and its documentation even says explicitly that it intended to be used with a method reference, like the OP’s second variant.