# Java Stream from Map to Map: Change Value inside Object while streaming

Tags: java, java-stream

I defined a map and filled it with 5 objects of the type `Rectangle`. Each Rectangle-object has the attributes `rectangleId`, `aLength`, `bLength` and `color`.

I want to use the java stream api to stream the given map into the new map. While streaming, the value of `bLength` shall be increased by 100 for all rectangles that are `red`. Below is what I got so far. I can't seem to figure out how to change the value of `bLength`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(800, 100,200,"green");
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(900, 200,300,"red");
        Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(1000, 300,400,"yellow");
        Rectangle r4 = new Rectangle(1100, 400,500,"blue");
        Rectangle r5 = new Rectangle(1200, 500,600,"orange");

        TreeMap<Integer, Rectangle> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
        myMap.put(r1.rectangleId, r1);
        myMap.put(r2.rectangleId, r2);
        myMap.put(r3.rectangleId, r3);
        myMap.put(r4.rectangleId, r4);
        myMap.put(r5.rectangleId, r5);

        Map<Integer, Rectangle> myMapNew = myMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(r -> r.getValue().color == "red")
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r.getKey(), r -> r.getValue()));

    }

    public class Rectangle {
        public int rectangleId;
        public int aLength;
        public int bLength;
        public String color;

        public Rectangle(int rectangleId, int aLength, int bLength, String color){
            this.rectangleId = rectangleId;
            this.aLength = aLength;
            this.bLength = bLength;
            this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the stream api? Seems straightforward to do in a for loop.

Comment: Must the result be a new map? By *modifying* the rectangles, there is only one instance of each, so the new map would be identical to the old map after your proposed operation. For the two maps to be different you would need to create new instances of the rectangles for the new map. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By *modifying* the rectangles, there is still only one instance of each, so the rectangles in *both* maps are the *same* rectangles and so new map would be identical to the old map after your proposed operation. Thus a new map is not required - modifying the old one is sufficient:

```
myMap.values().stream()
  .filter(r -> r.color.equals("red"))
  .forEach(r -> r.length += 100);
```

For the new map to be different, you would need to create new instance of the rectangles for the néw map, but that is not what you proposed.

Also note that comparing Strings using `==` is not guaranteed to work the way you expect in the general case; always use `.equals()`.

Answer (score 2):

So you have 2 steps in your streaming then:

1. incoming `Rectangle` to outgoing `Rectangle` (= identity)
2. convert one or many attributes of `Rectangle` based on a predicate (= conditional attribute-modification)

#### Solve it in functions

1. [identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t) (actually obsoletes this step in streaming), anyway:

```java
Function<Rectangle, Rectangle> toIdentical = Function.identity();
```

2. modification rule:

> `bLength` shall be increased by `100` for all `Rectangle`s that have property `color` with value `"red"`

```java
Function<Rectangle, Rectangle> toConditialModified = (rectangle) -> {
  if (rectangle.color.equals("red")) { // conditional
    rectangle.bLength += 100; // modified
  }
  return rectangle;
};
```

#### Then combine in a stream

Build a pipeline using these functional steps:

```java
Map<Integer, Rectangle> newRectanglesMap = oldRectanglesMap.values().stream()
  .map( toIdentical )  // can leave this out
  .map( toConditionalModified )
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r.rectangleId, r -> r));
```

#### Alternatively: update partly

Just work on the values, modify if needed in-place:

```java
oldRectanglesMap.values().stream()
  .filter(r -> r.color.equals("red")) // get only the red ones
  .forEach(r -> { r.bLength += 100; }) // modify the filtered
```

#### Over-readable & functionally decomposed

This would be better readable if decomposing `Function<Rectangle, Rectangle> toConditialModified` of previous step 2:

```java
Predicate<Rectangle> isRed = r -> r.color.equals("red");
Consumer<Rectangle> updateBLengthPlus100 = r -> r.bLength += 100;

oldRectanglesMap.values().stream()
  .filter( isRed )
  .forEach( updateBLengthPlus100 );
```

---

I just played with your code and requirement:

- looked on different aspects of the problem
- decomposed it differently
- solved these parts differently
- but: always functional using streams

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have all of the rectangles from the original map in the new map (and modify some of them) you can't use the `filter` method, because that will restrict the result to only the red ones.

You need to use the `map` method to change the rectangles while streaming:

```
Map<Integer, Rectangle> myMapNew = myMap.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().increaseBLengthOrReturnIdentity()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r.getKey(), r -> r.getValue()));
```

And you need to define the method `increaseBLengthOrReturnIdentity` in you `Rectangle` class:

```
public class Rectangle {
    public int rectangleId;
    public int aLength;
    public int bLength;
    public String color;

    public Rectangle(int rectangleId, int aLength, int bLength, String color){
        this.rectangleId = rectangleId;
        this.aLength = aLength;
        this.bLength = bLength;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Rectangle increaseBLengthOrReturnIdentity() {
        if (color.equals("red")) {//btw.: better use equals to compare strings instead of ==
            return new Rectangle(rectangleId, aLength, bLength + 100, color);
        }

        // you could also return 'this' here; depends on whether you need a new object or not
        return new Rectangle(rectangleId, aLength, bLength, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error:

Required type:

Function
<? super java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Integer,Rectangle>,
? extends R>
Provided:
<method reference>


reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Entry<Integer, Rectangle> conforms to Rectangle

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you stream over `Map.Entry<Integer, Rectangle>` objects instead of only `Rectangle` object. I updated the answer and tested it. Now it should be working.