# Compiletime error while using java.util.Function#identity in Stream#flatMap(Function<T,Stream<R>>)

Tags: java, java-stream

Merry Christmas,

I was tinkering with some java.util.Streams when some irregular behavior caught my eye.
I was simply trying to flatten a list containing several streams of integer values likes this example:

```java
List<Stream> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Stream.of( 1,2 ));
list.add(Stream.of( 3,4 ));

list.stream().flatMap( s -> s ).forEach( System.out::println );
```

This minimal code snippet works without any issue.
And usually when I see a lambda expression like `s -> s` I think I'd be able to simply replace it with `java.util.Function#identity()` since it's pretty much the same however in doing so I came upon this compile-time issue:

```
D:\Development\Java\Playground\src\Main.java:15:30
java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R,T
    (argument mismatch; java.util.function.Function<java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<? super java.util.stream.Stream,? extends java.util.stream.Stream<? extends java.lang.Object>>)
```

I myself cant quite explain the difference between using `java.util.Function#identity()` and `s -> s`. So why does this compile time issue occur? My guess is that it has something to do with type erasure but I am not certain and can't explain this for myself.

I am using OpenJDK v16.0.1.

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh... This is embarrassing. I absolutely forgot to declare the type of the stream which ultimately causes the error. Thank your for pointing this out to me. The code now works but still I can't quite figure out why the it didn't  work before. Shouldn't raw types be equal to `Type<Object>`? In that case Function#identity would return a Function<Stream<Object>,Stream<Object>> which in the end should work since it's operating on a Stream containing `Stream<Object> which should fulfill the requirements of Stream#flatMap

Comment: *Shouldn't raw types be equal to `Type<Object>`?* [No.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it#:~:text=how's%20a%20raw%20type%20different%20from%20using%20%3Cobject%3E%20as%20type%20parameters%3F) And raw types have cascading effects on the code that uses them.

Comment: You may want to look at: [Java 8 lambdas, Function.identity() or t ->t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t)

Comment: The compiler can warn you when you use raw types.  It’s a good idea to enable all compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.  Some of us even like using [-Werror](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-Werror) when we build…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you were going for.  The type should be `Stream<Integer>`

```
List<Stream<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Stream.of( 1,2 ));
list.add(Stream.of( 3,4 ));

list.stream().flatMap( s -> s ).forEach( System.out::println );
```

prints

```
1
2
3
4
```