# Can the Double Colon Operator reference the Source Object itself?

Tags: java, lambda

In certain cases when I use a Stream on a list of Objects, I like to collect them via the Collectors.toMap function and assign an important attribute as the key and the object itself as the value, like in this case:

```java
Map<String, SampleObject> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(SampleObject::getImportantValue, v -> v));
```

Usually I use the double colon operator to assign the key, but for the value I resort to the `v -> v` construct.

This made me wonder:

Is there a way to assign the object itself as the return value of the anonymous function by using double colons? From my own testing it appears that `SampleObject` and `SampleObject::` don't work. (Only logical, as the former only references the class and the latter expects a method to follow)

As a naive approach I would expect something functionally similar to this:

`...collect(Collectors.toMap(SampleObject::getImportantValue, SampleObject::));`

Comment: You can use `Function.identity()` instead of `v->v`.

Comment: Interesting, that works. I think you might as well post this as an answer, even though checking the implementation appears to just mask the arrow construct :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `v->v` you can use `Function.identity()`, which has the same effect. I personally like the second method more, but would not say that one is really better than the other. You can read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041480/7947994) about the differences if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the answer provided by JANO – either `t -> t` or `Function.identity()`.

However, if you *really really* want to use a method reference, you could just roll out your own method:

```java
class Functions {
    static <T> T identity(T t) {
        return t;
    }
}
```

and then suddenly

```java
.collect(Collectors.toMap(SampleObject::getImportantValue, Functions::identity));
```

works.