Why does Function.identity() return a lambda expression and not a cast static field that holds the identity lambda?
As seen in the JDK version I'm using source, Function.identity() is defined like this:
static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
    return t -> t;
}

To me, with old Java 7 and older versions background with their inner classes that can capture too much, it looks like the lambda in the identity function is kind of instantiated every time the Function.identity() function is invoked. I'm wondering what were the differences if the function would return a cast field?
For example, I have two classes that define lambdas in two ways from the above.
final class DynamicLambda {

    private DynamicLambda() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    static Function<Object, Object> identity() {
        return o -> o;
    }

}

final class StaticLambda {

    private StaticLambda() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    static final Function<Object, Object> identity = o -> o;

}

Their javap-ed classes are disassembled like this when using the -p and -c options:
Compiled from "DynamicLambda.java"
final class DynamicLambda {
  private DynamicLambda();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: new           #7                  // class java/lang/AssertionError
       7: dup
       8: invokespecial #9                  // Method java/lang/AssertionError."<init>":()V
      11: athrow

  static java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> identity();
    Code:
       0: invokedynamic #10,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:apply:()Ljava/util/function/Function;
       5: areturn

  private static java.lang.Object lambda$identity$0(java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: areturn
}

Compiled from "StaticLambda.java"
final class StaticLambda {
  static final java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> identity;

  private StaticLambda();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: new           #7                  // class java/lang/AssertionError
       7: dup
       8: invokespecial #9                  // Method java/lang/AssertionError."<init>":()V
      11: athrow

  private static java.lang.Object lambda$static$0(java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: areturn

  static {};
    Code:
       0: invokedynamic #10,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:apply:()Ljava/util/function/Function;
       5: putstatic     #14                 // Field identity:Ljava/util/function/Function;
       8: return
}

The only bytecode difference I see is that invokedynamic is invoked either as many times as the DynamicLambda.identity() is invoked, or one time for StaticLambda.identity in its static initializer.
From the semantic perspective, the advantage of the "dynamic" approach is lambda expression type inference, as the "static" approach would need unchecked type casting. From the call site perspective the only difference is instructions used to get the identity function: invokestatic for the "dynamic" approach, and getstatic for the "static" approach.
What is the real difference between these two and why is Function.identity() implemented like that? And how may they affect the memory footprint and possibly performance when invokedynamic is called multiple times?

Edit 1:
Please, this question is not really supposed to be about Function.identity() == Function.identity(). But true, I'm interested why it also behaves like that.

Edit 2:
As far as I understood the comments, it really depends on how a particular JVM optimizes code running at runtime (particularly inlining), and invokedynamic may take some time to lookup the same reference for Function.identity() somehow (how then? what's the identity of the lambda expression then?).
In short, what does invokedynamic do in the Function.identity() scenario?

What do you mean by "real difference"? You've already found many differences. What more are you looking for? Also note that since this is invokedynamic, a new object representing the lambda isn't necessarily allocated every time. On my machine (JDK 22), Function.identity() == Function.identity() is true.

@Sweeper My DynamicLambda.identity() == DynamicLambda.identity() is also true. For example, what time/performance impact does the Function.identity() have when invoked multiple times therefore invoking invokedynamic multiple times?

@terrorrussia-keeps-killing Little to none. Most probably inlined by JIT.

@talex Yes, it sounds very reasonable, but "little" is also a difference because it looks like it may depend on how JVM optimizes bytecode. Is there probably a way to tell if my JVM supports inlining like that? Or to tell if the true result might be optimized by javac itself (for example, javac "sees" the lambda expression is pure, and captures nothing from outer scope except of its arguments, be optimized even at compile time, especially if both Function.identity() calls return true)?

@terrorrussia-keeps-killing Please do not add "edit" sections to your question. Change the post instead so it is one complete question, not a question with patches on it.

@Progman I had this option in mind too, but I think that adding the edit sections reflects evolving of the question (mostly from the comments though) improving the question even if one doesn't read the question to the bottom. I believe it would be fair.

Based on title, possibly related: Does a lambda expression create an object on the heap every time it's executed?, especially this comment from
Brian Goetz (one of core Java architect responsible for adding lambdas to Java)

@Pshemo Thank you! This explains why Function.identity() may but not required to return the same reference (JLS 15.27.4). Also this sounds similar to what I thought javac also might do for pure non-capturing lambda expressions, kind of, but this is done in runtime, as far as I see, by invokedynamic (whatever is behind the scenes).

Regarding the interaction between the lambda expression and the invokedynamic instruction, see this comment

Function.identity() returns same instance every time.
So only difference is that it adjust to type  required by caller. Which give us type safety we want.
EDIT: I just found out that is implementation specific. Specification doesn't guarantee that.
Thanks to user85421:

JLS 15.27.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Lambda Expressions: "... This
implies that the identity of the result of evaluating a lambda
expression (...) is unpredictable, and therefore identity-sensitive
operations (such as reference equality (§15.21.3), object locking
(§14.19), and the System.identityHashCode method) may produce
different results in different implementations of the Java programming
language, or even upon different lambda expression evaluations in the
same implementation."


It is compiler optimization

JLS 15.27.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Lambda Expressions: "... This implies that the identity of the result of evaluating a lambda expression (...) is unpredictable, and therefore identity-sensitive operations (such as reference equality (§15.21.3), object locking (§14.19), and the System.identityHashCode method) may produce different results in different implementations of the Java programming language, or even upon different lambda expression evaluations in the same implementation."

Note that the decision to cache an instance representing a lambda expression is made at runtime, for that specific runtime, because the consequences are specific to that runtime. Caching might not always be the most efficient solution, e.g. optimizing environments may inline the operation up to the point that no instance is needed at all (as the behavior of an identity function surely doesn’t need the object) or have some kind of value-types being more efficient for temporary use than a singleton that persists after the operation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041480/2711488
