# How to populate a HashMap using a Lambda Expression

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, hashmap

There is one class (`SomeOrders`), which has few fields like `Id`, `Summary`, `Amount`, etc...

The requirement is to collect `Id` as key and `Summary` as value to a `HashMap` from an input `List` of `SomeOrder` objects.

Code in Before java 8:

```
List<SomeOrder> orders = getOrders();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (SomeOrder order : orders) {
    map.put(order.getId(), order.getSummary());
}
```

How to achieve the same with Lambda expression in Java 8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to convert List to Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map)

Comment: Yes, almost same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map
But above is just asked in general, from that one answer can find with Lambda expression. 
Anyhow thanks for notifying me.

Comment: Don't get confuse among *lambda expression* and *stream functional operations*. I think you would like to get answer for *functional operations*, as the answer below.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `Collectors.toMap` :

```
orders.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(SomeOrder::getID, SomeOrder::getSummary));
```

or

```
orders.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.getID(), o -> o.getSummary()));
```

Comment: What if the orders list has duplicates and the map should have a List to collect the order summaries ?
List<> to Map<String, List<String>>

Comment: How to populate an EnumMap like this ?