# how to convert list into map in java

Tags: java

I have arrayList

```
List<String> li= new ArrayList<String>() ;
li.add("a");
li.add("b");
```

I want to convert to ArrayList to HashMap Like this

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> s= new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

Please help me how to convert to HashMap

Comment: A map has keys and values.  Is your current list your keys or your values?

Comment: sorry HashMap<String,List<String>>= new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

Comment: You have list as a value for your map but what is key??

Comment: Is there more than one Arraylist of strings being stored as values in your HashMap?

Comment: what we do for key please tell me

Comment: Your key is whatever identifies the value (your ArrayList, in this case).  That is up to you.

Comment: i did not understand what you want to say @tangledUplnBlue

Comment: but how we convert this list to hashmap .tell me if any other option to convert list into map @TangledUpInBlue

Comment: A HashMap has keys and values.  You can put the List into your HashMap as a value (i.e. map.set(key, list)), or use the values in the list as keys, or as values.  It seems like you want to do the first.  Is that true?

Comment: ya bro that's why i have more confusion plz u provide any link through which i read the collection and i am able to solve my problem or provide me example @TangledUpInBlue

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html?

Comment: thanks bro for help @TangledUpInBlue

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post it as an answer to your own question so the post will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  final List<String> originalList = Arrays.asList("a","b");
    //JAVA 8
    //Always initialize maps/collections with their Interface
    final Map<Integer, String> mapFromListJavaEight =
            IntStream.range(0,originalList.size())
            .mapToObj(index -> index)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                    originalList::get));
    // JAVA < 8 & JAVA >= 5
    final Map<Integer, String> mapFromListJavaSeven =
            new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < originalList.size(); i++){
        mapFromListJavaSeven.put(i,originalList.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

[You need to look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map)
`List<Item> list;
    Map<Key,Item> map = new HashMap<Key,Item>();
    for (Item i : list) map.put(i.getKey(),i);`

Comment: but for this first we made the Item class after than we are able to do so. is it correct bro

Comment: It is depend on user needs , You can give String object or any other you want, Please View given link to more details

Comment: how plz give the example

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        int keyCount = 0;
        for (String i : list) {
            map.put(keyCount++, i);
        }
        System.out.println("Data: "+map);
    }

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String name;
          int  count=0; 
 List<String> li= new ArrayList<String>() ;
    li.add("a");
    li.add("d");
    li.add("b");
    li.add("e");
    Iterator i1 = li.iterator();
    while(i1.hasNext())
            {
        name = (String)i1.next();
        System.out.println(name);
            }

    HashMap <Integer,String> hm = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    for(String i : li)
    {
    hm.put(count++,i);
    }
    System.out.println("after converting list to map ");
    System.out.println(hm);
}
```