# Convert List<Object[]> Array into Map

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to make a Hashmap out of a List of Objects[] but I am unable to do so. Below is the code that I have written:

```
List<Object[]> adjustments =  query.getResultList();
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> dpaMap = adjustments.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> (Integer)a[0], a -> (BigDecimal)a[1]));
```

I know that only two fields are returning from the query they have the same Type as mentioned in Map, but its not working. Please guide me in this regard.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to convert List to Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map)

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/

Comment: Your code works fine to me (when the `Object[]` arrays contain what you say they do). I tried : `List<Object[]> adjustments =  new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    adjustments.add (new Object[] {Integer.valueOf (5),new BigDecimal(4)});
    adjustments.add (new Object[] {Integer.valueOf (55),new BigDecimal(48)});
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> dpaMap = adjustments.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> (Integer)a[0], a -> (BigDecimal)a[1]));`

Comment: @Sanka no, I want to use Java streams. Thanks

Comment: @Eran When I am debugging the code, it doesn't recognize a[0] and a[1] and when the 2nd line executes, it throws an exception

Comment: @MuhammadUmer What exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it seems that it was working fine, the column in the DB was returning Float so just had to cast it to BigDecimal

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> dpaMap = adjustments.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> (Integer)a[0], a -> BigDecimal.valueOf((Float) a[1])));
```

Thanks a lot people for your help.