# Java convert List<String> with delimeter to Hashmap<String, String>

Tags: string, list, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

Let

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("key1=value1", "key2=value2");
```

Is there a way in Java using the stream api to convert this to a HashMap?

i.e. {{key1 -> value1}, {key2 -> value2}}

```
HashMap<String, String> dataMap = data.stream().map(s -> s.split("=")).//some stuff here//.collect(//some stuff here//);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, String> map = data.stream()
                                  .map(s -> s.split("="))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1], (a, b) -> a, HashMap::new));
```

Comment: I definitely tried that, but it doesn't compile.

Array type expected; found: 'T'

Error: java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>
    upper bounds: java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,java.lang.Object

Comment: I updated the answer. I added a cast to `HashMap<String, String>`

Comment: This is because `Collectors.toMap` returns a `Map`, not a `HashMap`. Even though I would've argued against using HashMap, you can still do that by calling one of the overloaded `Collectors.toMap` implementations, where it allows you to specify your custom map supplier. Would look along the lines of `Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1], (a, b) -> a, HashMap::new)`. Note though that this will silently ignore duplicate map keys.

Comment: @Daniel, please revert your update back, it is very dangerous to cast results of collector operations. While it is true that current map collector uses `HashMap`, it is not guaranteed and may be changed at any moment without prior notice, at which point you will "suddenly" receive massive load of `ClassCastException`s.