# Converting a list of objects in java to a map of String key to List<objects> using one of its field as the key

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a list of objects `List<Car> cars`

```
public class Car{
  String make;
  String model;
  String year;
  String price;
}
```

I want a succinct way of converting this list to a map `Map<String, List<Car>>` using make as the key. I could write a function to do that but I was wondering if Lambdas or stream api in Java 8 provides an out of the box way to achieve this.

**I have modified the question for a `Map<String, List<Car>>`**

Comment: Well, you could use [How to convert List to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map) or if you really want to look l334, you could use [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v) or you could try one of the many logs you can find through Google like [Java 8 – Convert List to Map](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Comment: If you're using Guava: `Maps.uniqueIndex(cars, Car::getMake)`

Answer (score 4):

Yes its very well supported.

Do like this :

```
Map<String, List<Car>> youCarMap = yourCarList.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getMake,
                    Collectors.mapping(c->c, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Slight modification to the question. I actually also want to prepare a Map<String, List<Car>> makeToCars. How can I achieve this? @Shanu Gupta

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, List<Car>> result = 
          myList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getMake));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so

```
cars.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
      car -> car.make,
      Function.identity()
   )
```