# How to convert a list of objects into a map in Java 8?

Tags: list, collections, java-8, set, java-stream

I am trying to learn to do this in Java 8 using streams.

Given the follow:

```
List<PartModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
models.add(new PartModel("Part1", "AModel"));
models.add(new PartModel("Part1", "BModel"));
models.add(new PartModel("Part2", "AModel"));
```

I would like to convert this list into a map: `Map<String, Set<String>` where the values would be:

```
"Part1" -> ["AModel", "BModel"]
"Part2" -> ["AModel"]
```

How can I achieve this with using a Java 8 stream?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to convert List to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `groupingBy` collector like this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> partModelMap = models.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Partmodel::getPart,
               Collectors.mapping(Partmodel::getModel, Collectors.toSet())));
```

The `Collectors.mapping` part will map the values of the map from `List<PartModel>` to a `Set<String>`.

Answer (score 2):

We can group by `getPart()` and then return a     `Map<Integer, Set<String>>`

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> collect = models.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PartModel::getPart, 
                Collectors.mapping(PartModel::getModel), Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: @c0der it shouldn't be. OP wants `Map<String, Set<String>>`

Answer (score 1):

A simple stream grouping by the first field and transforming the groups can look like this:

```
    Map<String, String[]> map = models.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PartModel::getPartName,
                Collectors.mapping(PartModel::getModelName, Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, 
        entry -> entry.getValue().toArray(new String[entry.getValue().size()])));
```