# How to insert the same value for multiple keys of an HashMap using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Say I have a HashMap and I want to insert the same value to a list of keys. How can I do this with Java 8 without iterating through all the keys and inserting the value? This is more of a Java Streams question.

Here is the straight forward way of doing it. This is a sample code that I wrote to demonstrate what I wanted to achieve.

```
public void foo(List<String> keys, Integer value) {
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>(); 
    for (String key : keys) {
        myMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way of doing the above using Java 8 streams? How can I avoid the for loop using Java 8 streams. Thanks!

[Edit-1] A better code snippet below.

```
public void foo() {
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>(); 
    List<String> keys = getKeysFromAnotherFunction();
    Integer value = getValueToBeInserted(); // Difficult to show my actual use case. Imagine that some value is getting computed which has to be inserted for the keys.
    for (String key : keys) {
        myMap.put(key, value);
    }  

    List<String> keys2 = getNextSetOfKeys();
    Integer newValue = getValueToBeInserted(); 
    for (String key : keys2) {
        myMap.put(key, newValue);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is `myMap` actually defined outside the `foo` method?

Comment: Yes. that is right. This is not the actual code. It is a small code snippet that I quickly came up to better explain what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: It could hardly be simpler than that. You need a loop. There's no shortcut.

Comment: There's no way to do this without iterating (unless "iterating" excludes `keys.forEach(e -> myMap.put(e, value);`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to convert List to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map)

Comment: This is not about converting list to a map as I am aware of that. I want to add a same value to a bunch of keys of a Map.

Comment: Your idea is pretty straight forward.  No need to use streams (they can incur signifcant overhead) but you might want to consider generalizing for "foo" method to take a list of keys and a value.  And also consider using myMap.putIfAbsent() if you don't want to accidentally replace an existing value.

Comment: Unfortunately, the following only works for `ConcurrentHashMap`:
 `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        myMap.keySet(getValueToBeInserted()).addAll(getKeysFromAnotherFunction());`

Answer (score 6):

Using collector, something like:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = keys.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key,
                    val -> value, (a, b) -> b));
```

Comment: This is not "a simpler way" (a stated requirement) and does not use a myMap that is defined outside of the method (another stated requirement).

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like this.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I would say "simpler" could be opinion based then. Anyway not sure what is the `myMap` outside the method context you've commented about. The variable `myMap` seems local to the method in the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is about factoring out some piece of code more than converting traditional `for` loops into stream constructs.

Suppose you have the following generic utility method:

```
public static <K, V, M extends Map<K, V>> M fillMap(
        Supplier<List<K>> keysFactory,
        Supplier<V> singleValueFactory,
        Supplier<M> mapFactory) {

    M map = mapFactory.get();
    List<K> keys = keysFactory.get();
    V singleValue = singleValueFactory.get();

    keys.forEach(k -> map.put(k, singleValue));

    return map;
}
```

Then, you could use the above method as follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = fillMap(() -> getKeysFromAnotherFunction(),
                                     () -> getValueToBeInserted(),
                                     HashMap::new); // create HashMap

myMap = fillMap(() -> getNextSetOfKeys(),
                () -> getValueToBeInserted(),
                () -> myMap); // use previously created map
```

There are variants for the code above, i.e., the method could receive a `Map<K, V>` instance instead of a `Supplier<Map<K, V>>`, or it might even be overloaded to support both variants.