# Is there a way to bind a ObservableList to a ObservableMap?

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, hashmap, javafx-8

I get data in the format of an `ObservableMap<T, Foo>`.
To implement this data in a View I need the values of that map in the format of an `ObservableList<Foo>`.

Because I need the data in a Map Collection (to avoid duplicates and other reasons) I was wondering if it is possible to **bind** these 2 collections.

**Something like:**

```
ObservableMap<Integer, Foo> data = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
ObservableList<Foo> target = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

// Won't work 
Bindings.bindContent(target, data.values());
```

Binding because the data can change during runtime.

**Edit:**
Initializing the List with map values is not working because the there will be addtional Foo's added to the map:
Example with a String as map value:

```
ObservableMap<Integer, String> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
map.put(1, "a");
map.put(2, "b");

ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.value());

//map = {1=a, 2=b}
//list = [a, b]
// ok

map.put(3, "c");

//map = {1=a, 2=b, 3=c}
//list = [a, b]
// no update
```

Comment: Did you tried with streams? Like described from Alexis C. in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map

Comment: https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind

Comment: @ConstantinBeer my data Map is getting new values over time so I want to keep the map and the list with the same values. Streams wont update if there are changes as far as I know.

Comment: does the observable list needs to be modifiable? If not, it's relatively (details and devils are close friends <g>) easy to implement a custom TransformedList that's backed by the map

Comment: @SURU I can't seem to find a suitable method to bind a map with a list in EasyBinding, only list to list.

Comment: in the most simple case (only map is changed, list is read-only) you can manually listen to changes in the map and replace the items in the list

Comment: yes i will try that approach

Comment: @thober35 You are right, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

from ObservableMap  to ObservableList

```
ObservableMap<Integer, Foo> data = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
ObservableList<Foo> target = FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.values());
```

Comment: i want to keep target updated. once initialized with data.values() no changes in data are recognized.

Comment: no, as the api doc of observableArrayList(Collection) clearly states _Creates a new observable array list and adds a content of collection col to it._

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah but he want to bind them, and after adding new values to the map put it automatically in list without additional updating it again, so your solution won't work.

Comment: @SURU a) never (yet, maybe I'll do later) posted a _solution_. If you mean my comment/s: b) manual listeners will always work c) I was wrong in suggesting a custom transformList (requires the backing source to be a list) - a custom ObservableList backed by an ObservableMap would do, though

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a built in solution in Java. I use a simple MapChangeListener when the Map is the source of the data, and the List is only for tracking changes to the Map value list.

```
    ObservableMap<String, String> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    MapChangeListener<String, String> listener = c -> {
        if (c.wasRemoved()) {
            list.remove(c.getValueRemoved());
        }

        if (c.wasAdded()) {
            list.add(c.getValueAdded());
        }
    };

    map.addListener(listener);

    map.put("1", "A");
    map.put("2", "B");
    map.put("1", "A'");

    assertThat(list).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("A'", "B");
```

You should keep the observable list private, and only expose a unmodifiableObservableList externally, to prevent accidently adding list entries that are not in the map.

Comment: I created a utility class for this. That way it is easy to reuse the code. You can find the Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/aron-hoogeveen/757c71edddfa18c207870a3e62e28571)