# Rewrite imperative code of creating and populating Map in a declarative way using Java Stream API

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have this piece of code :

```
Map<String, BillingAccount> billingAccountsMap = new HashMap<>();
for (BillingAccount ba : billingAccounts) {
    if (ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier() != null && ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier() != null) {
        billingAccountsMap.put(ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier(), ba);
    }
}
```

All I want is to rewrite it in a functional way with Java Stream API and `collect(Collectors.toMap())`, but I am a bit perplexed with the `null` cases.

I am using Java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out nullable values using [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) operation and then apply `collect` by passing a built-in collector [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) into it:

```
Map<String, BillingAccount> billingAccountsById = billingAccounts.stream()
    .filter(account -> Objects.nonNull(account.getBillingAccountIdentifier()))
    .filter(account -> Objects.nonNull(account.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        account -> account.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier(), // keyMapper
        Function.identity())); // valueMapper
```

Note that for this approach, every identifier has to be unique. Otherwise, you need to provide `mergeFunction` as the third argument to resolve values mapped to the same key.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Collectors.toMap(..)` to convert a stream of items to a map, and `filter()` to remove items you don't want. In your case:

```
var billingAccountsMap = billingAccounts.stream()
        .filter(ba -> ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier() != null)
        .filter(ba -> ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ba -> ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier(), ba -> ba));
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887747/6334782) for more information.

Comment: I liked the var detail :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, BillingAccount> billingAccountsMap = billingAccounts.stream()
        .filter(ba -> ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier() != null
                && ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ba -> ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier(), ba -> ba));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could stream your `List` of `BillingAccount`, then use the aggregate operation `filter` to make sure that each `BillingAccount` and its nested fields are not null with a short-circuited condition. Finally, collect the results where each key is the `BillingAccount`'s identifier while the corresponding value is the object itself.

```
Map<String, BillingAccount> billingAccountsMap = billingAccounts.stream()
        .filter(ba -> Objects.nonNull(ba) 
                && Objects.nonNull(ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier()) 
                && Objects.nonNull(ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ba -> ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier(), Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupingBy` once `filter`  for null checks got applied:

```
billingAccounts.stream()
        .filter(ba -> ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier() != null
                        && ba.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier() != null)
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getBillingAccountIdentifier().getIdentifier()));
```

Comment: This creates  a Map<String, List<BillingAccount>>